# A travelling field; Feynman lectures on Physics Volume 2

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

In Feynman's Lectures on Physics, volume 2, Chapter 18 (18-5), we look at the creation of a electromagnetic field, due to a moving infinite sheet of charge,

> By looking at the Maxwell equations alone, it is not easy to see
>   directly how to get the solution. So we will first show you what the
>   answer is and then verify that it does indeed satisfy the equations.
>   The answer is the following: The field B that we computed is, in fact,
>   generated right next to the current sheet (for small x). **It must be
>   so, because if we make a tiny loop around the sheet, there is no room
>   for any electric flux to go through it** $^*$. But the field B out
>   farther—for larger x—is, at first, zero. It stays zero for awhile, and
>   then suddenly turns on. In short, we turn on the current and the
>   **magnetic field immediately next to it turns on to a constant value B** ;
>   then the turning on of B spreads out from the source region. After a
>   certain time, there is a uniform magnetic field everywhere out to some
>   value x, and then zero beyond. Because of the symmetry, it spreads in
>   both the plus and minus x-directions.

**Questions:**

$^*$ What does he mean, by "there's no room for electric flux to go through" , why does it conclude, "magnetic field immediately next to it turns on to a constant value B"? How can this be, how can magnetic field suddenly attain a constant value, it has to increase from 0 shouldn't it ?